# Solve Git problem to avoid storing filenames/paths having backslash chars, which are invalid in Windows

Tags: git, gitignore, repo, invalid-characters

I would like to solve Git problem to avoid storing filenames/paths having backslash chars, which are invalid in Windows, like `/etc/systemd/system/snap-git\x2dfilter\x2drepo-7.mount`.

I should add a specific string to .gitignore to avoid storing filenames/paths mentioned above.

I tried in `.gitignore`

```
/*\*/
snap-git
```

But the snap-git\x2dfilter\x2drepo-7.mount file was still added to the Git repo.

What would be the right regular expression to exclude these invalid files from Git repo?

I don't have idea why the `/*\*/` and `snap-git` does not work in .gitignore.

What I do wrong?
Maybe .gitignore does not match the full path, just the filename itself?
This is the point I'm wrong?

EDIT1:
I found the following info in .gitignore doc:

```
Two consecutive asterisks ("**") in patterns matched against full pathname 
may have special meaning:

A trailing "/**" matches everything inside. For example, "abc/**" 
matches all files inside directory "abc", relative to the location of 
the .gitignore file, with infinite depth.
```

So instead of `snap-git` pattern, I have to use `trailing "/**"` to match all files inside directory `snap-git`:

```
snap-git/**
```

Comment: I'm guessing you need a line with `*\\*`. LMK if that works and I can make it an answer.

Comment: Note that `.gitignore` only works on untracked files, so if any of the files are already committed and currently tracked, then modifications to those file will still show up as changes, regardless of `.gitignore` entries. In that case you'll need to delete the files, and commit that deletion, so that `.gitignore` will prevent them from getting added from then on.

Comment: @TTT Thank you very much for the ideas. I will test the suggestion tomorrow.

Comment: I don't have idea why the `/*\*/` and
`snap-git` does not work in .gitignore. What I did wrong?

Comment: Did you try my suggestion? My assumption is `/*\*/` didn't work because you need two slashes instead of one. (You must escape the backslash with another backslash.) Also the trailing `/` signifies a directory instead of a file. The reason `snap-git` doesn't work is because you don't have a file or directory named "snap-git". The reason `snap-git/**` doesn't work is also because you don't have a directory named "snap-git". BTW, I'm guessing `snap-git*` would have worked.

Comment: I added, but it's rarely reproduced by the system. Can I reproduce it manually?

Comment: Create a file with the backslash character in it and see if it ignores it?